# Making open-source CSS class/id names unique

Tags: css

I'm trying to make all class/id names in a stylesheet unique, for example Bootstrap or some other open-source CSS framework.

I've found a list of all class names in Bootstrap 3, ex:

```
.col-sm-1
.col-sm-2
.col-sm-3
...
```

I'm going to be building a form using Bootstrap CSS that will be used on another websites (think Stripe's modal that you paste into your website and it maintains their styles).

However, if I leave the Bootstrap CSS classes and ids untouched there will be all sorts of problems with conflicting styles with other's websites.

Is there a way to preface or append my company's name or a random string to every single style in the stylesheet so that there won't be problems with conflicting styles?

Ex:

```
.col-sm-1-abc123
.col-sm-2-abc123
...
```

Having the styles above will most likely not cause problems with conflicting styles.  But, it would require appending "-abc123" to every style.

Is there a way to do this? If so, how?  If not, what's the alternative to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: wrap your HTML in a element with a unique id, and next wrap the entire stylesheet inside that selector

Comment: Can you show an example @BrianGlaz

Answer (score 1):

If you need to prevend name problems, then you should use namespaces. That you can do very easy with Less, example:

```
.your_namespace_name {

   // Here your Less/CSS code, for example the whole bootstrap css/less
}
```

Then you give your body or the top div the class of your_namespace_name:

```
<body class="your_namespace_name">
```

Comment: And then inside `<body>` use the styles as I normally would?

Comment: Yes! In the compiled CSS, all of your selectors are addressed by the namespace name. It's very easy and one of the main reasons to use Less or Sass.

Comment: So I can literally take the bootstrap.min.css and copy it inside of the snippet above, and then in my HTML use <body class="custom_style"></body> and inside the body use the bootstrap classes without any conflicting problems?

Comment: Yes, but you have a Less-file, which you have to compile to CSS. The compiler is doing all the work for you. Less is easy to use and gives your CSS more structure and the possibility to use dependencies, variables and calculations.

Comment: Is LESS required, or could I just copy in bootstrap.min.css contents inside of the custom named style?

Comment: You need Less only during developing. There is no browser which can read less files.

Comment: Trying it in my web app right now, and it's not working.

Comment: Put styles in stylesheet nested inside of `.custom { //styles here }` then in my HTML I have `<body class="custom"> <div class="bootstrapelementhere"></div></body>` and it's using the styles from my app, not bootstrap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87425/discussion-between-joerg-and-noah).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, possible. You can rebuild the stylenames from their source code using their documentation.

You have a whole lot of options to [Customize Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) in their site, where you can give prefix and suffix for all the classes.

Comment: What about something other than Bootstrap?  Like a material design CSS framework?

Comment: You cannot target all the CSS frameworks. Can you? If you wanna do, try adding a prefix for your framework.

Comment: Not seeing where I can do this @ http://getbootstrap.com/customize.  Can you point it out to me?

Comment: It is better to wear a footwear than covering the whole world with a carpet. Right?